# Is it true that for Cobb-Douglas preferences, the demand function is always iso-elastic?

Tags: microeconomics, utility, elasticity, cobb-douglas

As we know that $Q*P=const.$ for Cobb-Douglas preferences, we can thus conclude that $\frac{dQ/Q}{dP/P}$ is always $-1$:

$$
QP=const. \implies 0=d(PQ)=Q\ dP+P\ dQ \implies \frac{dQ}{Q}=-\frac{dP}{P}
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will be a weird answer:

---

As we know that $Q*P=const.$ for Cobb-Douglas preferences.

$$
QP=const. \implies 0=d(PQ)=Q\ dP+P\ dQ \implies \frac{dQ}{Q}=-\frac{dP}{P}
$$
thus we can conclude that $\frac{dQ/Q}{dP/P}$ is always $-1$.

Comment: @j3141592653589793238 I still don't know what you were asking, I copied the answer from the body of your question.

Comment: I'm asking whether the assumption about Cobb-Douglas preferences always leading to iso-elastic demand curves is correct. Should I avoid such yes/no questions? Sorry. I just wasn't  quite sure. @Giskard

Comment: The part that puzzles me is how you could not decide based on the evidence you yourself gave. I gave the same reasoning as you did; how was this helpful?

Comment: I didn't know if the approach was correct and I'm still learning and I couldn't find a passage in my textbook that said that explicitly.

Comment: Allright. If you feel my copying the body of your question into an answer helped, you are welcome.

Comment: Sure, just needed some confirmation from a professional! :) @Giskard

Comment: I added an answer for extra confirmation ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

I have to include at least 30 characters in an answer, so let me repeat: Yes.

Comment: Cheers. I feel very much confirmed now indeed.